# log4cxx time based rolling on Windows

Tags: winapi, rollingfileappender, log4cxx

Has anyone had any success getting log4cxx to roll files based upon time on Windows?  It seems from the unit test cases and the behavior I can observe that this does not work at all on win32 platforms.

My config is below in case I've made a mistake there:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.File=C:\\logs\\out.log
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want to be using a DailyRollingFileAppender ?